Flutter: Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppSearchBatchResult has failures
I'm getting this after uploading it on play store and after upgrading to flutter 3.22
Device : google Pixel 6
ABI: arm64-v8a
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppSearchBatchResult has failures: {
  successes: {}
  failures: {https://g.co/pixeltips/tips_fix_subjects?LaunchFrom=APP_SEARCH=[FAILURE(6)]: Schema type config 'com.google.android.apps.tips$/Tip' not found}
}
  at androidx.a.a.b.a (AppSearchBatchResult.java:1)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.platform.a.d (PlatformIndex.java:11)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.b.a (TipsIndexingHelper.java:20)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.d.run (TipsIndexingJobService.java:1)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)```

 i expect the app to work properly


After spending hours, i found that minification that causes the issue so there is 2 solutions:
First:
android {
    buildTypes {
      debug {
        minifyEnabled = false
        shrinkResources = false
      }
      release {
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.release

        minifyEnabled = false
        shrinkResources = false
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
      }
   }
}

Second:
add this line in proguard-rules.pro
-keep class androidx.core.graphics.drawable.** { *; }

